# regex in R doesn't work as it does somewhere else

Tags: r, regex

I have a sentence and a query as on the image. It works as I want. But I really stuck while porting it to R.

[image]

My R query is:
`gsub("\\S*[^[:alnum:]\\s\\?\\!\",();:\\.'\\/-]+\\S*", "", x)`

and it cuts everything. I can't find my error.
Even the shorter with alnum: `"\\S*[^[:alnum:]]+\\S*"` cuts everything.
I don't understand. Please help.

Comment: What do you need to get in the end? Are you going to remove the matches, or *extract* them?

Comment: Could you please share the regex101 fiddle link? Also, since you test a PCRE regex and are using a TRE one, try `gsub("\\S*[^[:alnum:]\\s?!\",();:.'/-]+\\S*", "", x, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: Great thanks! perl=True is the answer. I do really forgot about this option. Removing from the text is the issue, now it works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `\s` shorthand class in the TRE bracket expression, replace with `[:space:]`, and unescape all the other "special" chars because you should not escape them either (they already match literal symbols).

```
pat <- "\\S*[^[:alnum:][:space:]?!\",();:.'/-]+\\S*"
x <- "But what's about in a interacting QFT a 2-particla state in the far past: $|E_{\\bf p_1}, {\\bf p_1}, E_{\\bf p_2} {\\bf p_2}&gt;$ which undergoes"
gsub(pat, "", x)
```

Note that even `gsub(pat, "", x, perl=TRUE)` will also work.

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/sGjcKf)